# Getting Client IP Address in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

How can I get the client's IP Address? When I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` I get something like [::1]:12473

When I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` I keep getting ::1

Comment: That *is* an IP address. It's IPv6. I mean, the first one has a port number after it, but ::1 is an IP address. Specifically, localhost. The equivalent of 127.0.0.1 in IPv4.

Comment: @itsme86 Right, but that's the ip address of localhost right? What about the client's ip address

Comment: Are you not accessing the website from the server?

Comment: @itsme86 the website is hosted on Azure. I want to get the ip address of the client's who are accessing the website from their browser

Comment: Oh maybe that's some kind of weird Azure thing. You're looking in the right places as far as I can tell.

Comment: I dont think it's a "weird" bug or anything, your probably using a service like apache or nginx to forward messages and obviously those services ip is localhost. depending on the service you use there are flags you can add to the conf files to forward the external ip.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I keep having sessions randomly starting in production, even when no one is touching the app. Always in chunks of four from the localhost ip address. I can't figure out what is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

When you run your code local, you get a ::1 (localhost).
If you publish to Azure, you should get the correct IP address.

You can expand your code by checking for the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header as well. This returns the correct client IP address when proxies and/or load balancers are involved.

```
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
{
    ipAddress = HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using that same code. When I hit the website published to Azure on my laptop home WiFi connection it gives me something like [::1]:12473 but when I hit it from my phone on LTE it gave me a more typical looking ip address like 91.458.910.178:14912